# Active admin type package for node.js

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

Is there any package similar to active admin used in Ruby on Rails which can help with user management and authentication.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Lumber](https://www.forestadmin.com/lumber/). This is the only solution I know of, you may need to develop something custom.